# How to send emails through Django using a private domain email address?

Tags: python, django, django-email

I registered a domain and a private email using namecheap.com. I am trying to send an email from this private email. However, I get the error in the title.

In my settings.py, I have these settings:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'mail.privateemail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'contact@mysite.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'my password'
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
```

And I am trying to send the email through a view:

```
send_mail(
    'Subject here',
    'Here is the message.',
    'contact@mysite.com',
    ['myname@gmail.com'],
    fail_silently=False,
)
```

However, I get this error when I load the view, and try to send the email:

```
SMTPServerDisconnected at /
Connection unexpectedly closed: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer
```

What am I doing wrong? And how can I fix this? Thanks.

**EDIT**

After changing the port to 587, I get the following error:

```
SMTPException at /
STARTTLS extension not supported by server.
```

Any idea why? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

```
EMAIL_HOST = os.getenv("EMAIL_HOST")
EMAIL_PORT = os.getenv("EMAIL_PORT")
EMAIL_USE_SSL = os.getenv("EMAIL_USE_SSL")
EMAIL_HOST_USER =  os.getenv("EMAIL_HOST_USER")
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.getenv("EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD")
```

using `SSL` instead of `TLS` solved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `EMAIL_USE_TLS = True` it will not work for hosted domain email.

Use `EMAIL_USE_SSL = True`

here is full configs

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'mail.<domain>.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '<some_name>@<domain>.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '<user_password>'
EMAIL_PORT = 465
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using port 587 (TLS) instead of 465 (SSL): https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9183/2175/email-account-setup-in-microsoft-outlook-20072010-smtpimappop3

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the input. However, after changing the port, I get this error: **STARTTLS extension not supported by server.** Any idea why?

Comment: Hmm this is really strange - the documentation of privatemail says that TLS is supported. Maybe contact their technical support ?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this same issue on Namecheap but the Namecheap support staff didn't solve this problem. I got an answer on StackOverflow.
that error show because we used EMAIL_PORT = 465.

```
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_USE_SSL = False
```

set 587 port no. definitely you resolve this error. if you using 465 then change this  EMAIL_USE_SSL = True and EMAIL_USE_TLS = False.